# Substract one integer from another and save

Tags: django, django-views

I need to substract one integer form another and save the result. Its some kind of payment method. Never do that before, so the code below - its what I'm trying to do in my view:

```
def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):
    if request.POST:
        article = Article.objects.filter(id=article_id) 
        article.article_users.add(request.user)

        balance = int(UserProfile.objects.filter(balance=user_balance))
        cost = int(Article.objects.filter(cost=article_cost))
        new_balance = balance - cost

        article.save()
```

So I hooked up `User` to `Article` model first. Then I need to substract `Article` model field `article_cost` from `UserProfile` model (that extends `User` with `ForeignKey`) field `user_balance` and save the result back to `user_balance`...

As you can see in above code, I tried to make substraction, but how can I save result back to `user_balance` now?

Also, am I need `int` converter, if both fields in both models works as `IntegerField` already?

My app `article`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    article_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    article_content = models.IntegerField(choices=CONTENT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    article_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    article_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My app `userprofile`:

```
import PIL

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.db import models
from article.models import Article

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users', blank=False, null=False, default='users/big-avatar.jpg')
    user_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u) [0])
```

Also I created an app `orderstatus`, that need to save order history in DB:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from article.models import Article

class OrderHistory(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'order'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And write a view for it (that you can see at the beginning of that post):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect, Http404
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib import auth
from django.template import RequestContext
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from article.models import Article
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):
    if request.POST:
        article = Article.objects.filter(id=article_id) 
        article.article_users.add(request.user)

        balance = int(UserProfile.objects.filter(balance=user_balance))
        cost = int(Article.objects.filter(cost=article_cost))
        new_balance = balance - cost

        article.save()
```

Comment: Please provide your `models.py` so we can get a better understanding of the scope. Also, where does `user_balance` come from?

Comment: @Hybrid Post updated. Provided all the data, that can help to you, I think...

Comment: `user_balance ` is not provided in your view!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an MVT (Model View Template) point of view, the balance modification of the `UserProfile` should be handled in the model it self not in the view.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    ## fields
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def withdraw(self, amount):
        # you will need to check here if the 
        # balance is enough for this transaction or not
        self.balance = self.balance - amount


    def can_purchase_amount(self, amount):
        return True if amount <= self.balance
```

views.py

```
def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):
    """
    Make the transaction
    """
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    article = Article.objects.filter(id=article_id)


    # check if the user can purhcase this
    if user_profile.can_purchase_amount(article.article_cost):
        # the user have enough balance to make this payment
        user_profile.withdraw(article.article_cost)
        user_profile.save()

        # add the user to the article
        article.article_users.add(request.user)

        # other things like register order or log

    else:
        # no enough balance
```

Indeed, this code is not complete for a real money transactions, however it demonstrate who should do what. You will need probably to lock the balance of the user before submitting the transaction in order to make sure that there were no duplicates. Also you might want to log this for future invitations

Comment: Othman, finally, I got it working...))) Thx a lot. Also, can you tell me, how to show the list of all users, who connected to article in template? I tried `{{ article.article_users.user.username }}` and got nothing... As I think, I need `for` cycle with something?

Comment: Since it's `ManyToManyField` then indeed you will need to iterate through the users. you can use the field name `{% for a in article.article_users.all %}` which will loop through the users who purchased this article.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to rewrite checkoutstatus as follows:

```
def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):
    if request.POST:
        article = Article.objects.filter(id=article_id) 
        article.article_users.add(request.user)

        balance = int(UserProfile.objects.filter(balance=user_balance))
        cost = int(Article.objects.filter(cost=article_cost))
        new_balance = balance - cost

        profile_to_update = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile_to_update.user_balance = new_balance
        profile_to_update.save()

        article.save()
```

But this is not the standard way. Check @Othman's answer for better implementation idea.